# Filtering out binary data

Tags: perl, filter, binary-data

Makes this subroutine sense, if I want find binary data?

```
sub is_binary_data {
    my $data = shift;
    return $data =~ /\x00/;
}
```

Comment: No, it doesn't make any sense. The binary representation of `0x41424344` is `ABCD`. How you can filter out binary data when the only different binary data and text is in how you interpret the very same bytes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may try this:

```
sub is_binary_data {
  my $data = shift;
  return $data =~ /[\x00-\x1F]/;
}
```

this should return true if your data contains any character below \x20 (being the latter a blank space).

Comment: I think you mean `\x1F`, unless you are working in base 11 :)

Answer (score 2):

There is always `-B`*filename*, which returns "true" if the file is binary.  But, as amon says, it depends on your definition of binary.  From *perlfunc*:

"*The first block or so of the file is examined for odd characters such as strange control codes or characters with the high bit set. If too many strange characters (>30%) are found, it's a -B file*"

Answer (score 1):

That depends on your definition of "binary data", and on the input encoding. If your script uses no encoding and looks at raw bytes, you will find null bytes even in ordinary text files, e.g. when they are encoded in UTF-16 (hello, Windows!).

If you decode your input and operate on characters (not bytes), only the `NUL`-character will trigger your binary detection. However, that only works when you *know* the encoding. And binary files aren't usually encoded.

In the end, this is a chicken-or-egg problem. In the case of ASCII and ASCII-compatible encodings, your solution (using the @sergio extended range) will work if operating on bytes, but it will produce false positives.

```
use Encode;
my $text = "abc";
my ($utf16bytes,$utf8bytes) = map{encode $_, $text} qw(UTF-16 UTF-8);
say "UTF-16 bytes contain NUL bytes." if $utf16bytes =~ /\x00/;
say "UTF-8  bytes contain NUL bytes." if $utf8bytes  =~ /\x00/;
```

Output:

```
UTF-16 bytes contain NUL bytes.
```

Comment: The data comes from a SQLite database. I want to filter out all the data which looks like garbage (the data which is normally stored in binary data types like blob image or binary).